# Inserting Custom post type in wordpress without plugins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

the problem is this (There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.)

I put the code in function.php which this

```
function create_posttype() {
  
    register_post_type( 'movies',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
  
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

im expecting that on left side in wordpress it show "Movies" like "Post, Pages, Media and many more"

my question is what is my possibly wrong and what am i gonna do to fix this.

im humbly thankyou for your response.

Comment: Enable debug and see what is the error. The code its fine. https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('init', 'custom_post');
function custom_post() {
    register_post_type('behandelingen',
        array(
            'label'                 => 'Behandelingen',
            'singular_label'        => 'Behandelingen',
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'public'                => true,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'dfbehandelingen'),
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'has_archive'           => true,
            'menu_position'         => 5,
            'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-networking',
            'supports'              => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'page-attributes'),
        )
    );

    
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can find tips in the official WordPress documentation on [registering post types](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/).

For an easier approach, create a new file for your custom post type, like `movies-cpt.php`, and include it in the `functions.php` file.

Inside `movies-cpt.php`, use this template to create your custom post type:

```php
function register_movies_cpt()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x('Movies', 'text_domain'),
        'singular_name'         => _x('Movie', 'text_domain'),
        'menu_name'             => _x('Movies', 'text_domain'),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x('Movies', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new'               => __('Add New', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new_item'          => __('Add New item', 'text_domain'),
        'new_item'              => __('New item', 'text_domain'),
        'edit_item'             => __('Edit item', 'text_domain'),
        'view_item'             => __('View item', 'text_domain'),
        'all_items'             => __('All items', 'text_domain'),
        'search_items'          => __('Search items', 'text_domain'),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __('Parent items:', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found'             => __('No items found.', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __('No items found in Trash.', 'text_domain'),
        'archives'              => _x('item archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'technway'),
        'insert_into_item'      => _x('Insert into item', 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'technway'),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x('Uploaded to this item', 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'technway'),
        'filter_items_list'     => _x('Filter items list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'technway'),
        'items_list_navigation' => _x('items list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'technway'),
        'items_list'            => _x('items list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'technway'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                 => true,
        'publicly_queryable'     => true,
        'show_ui'                => true,
        'show_in_menu'           => true,
        'query_var'              => true,
        'capability_type'        => 'post',
        'has_archive'            => true,
        'hierarchical'           => false,
        'menu_position'          => null,
        'field'                  => 'value',
        'menu_icon'              => 'dashicons-format-video',
        'taxonomies'             => array(''),
        'supports'               => array(
                                        'title', // Add the title field
                                        'thumbnail', // Add the thumbnail
                                        'excerpt' // Add the excerpt field
                                    ),
        'show_in_rest'          => true
    );
    register_post_type('movies_cpt', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'register_movies_cpt');
```

And to display your created movie items, you can use the following code:

```php
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'movies_cpt',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
        $the_query->the_post();
?>

        <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif; ?>
```

You can replace 'dashicons-format-video' with the [desired dashicon](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#format-video).
For additional information and explanation, explore the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)